# renderUI not evaluated until it is rendered

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a shiny app with a selectInput dynamically populated with a reactive function, created via renderUI. The selectInput is in a separate "configuration" tabpanel.
I noticed that after running the App the input$id value remains NULL until I click on the tabPanel where the uiOutput() resides. Then after it is rendered, input$id is assigned with the "selected" value.

I tried to use req(input$id) where needed but it did not work. If I try running req(input$id) in the Debug console the error returned is just "Error: ". I also tried with shinydashboard but got the same behaviour.

I created a minimal reproducible example. The textOutput in the tabPanel "A" should display the choice of the selectInput. But until you clic on the second tabPanel, it shows nothing.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("one", textOutput('text')),
    tabPanel("two",
             uiOutput('select'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  c <- reactive({
    list("A", "B", "C")
  })

  output$select <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      inputId = "choice",
      label = "Select input",
      choices = c(),
      selected = 1
    )
  })

  output$text <- renderText(
    input$choice
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I directly put a selectInput in the second tabPanel (without renderUI), input$choice is initialised right from the app start

e.g.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("one", textOutput('text')),
    tabPanel("two",
             selectInput(
               inputId = "choice",
               label = "Select input",
               choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
               selected = 1
             ))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$text <- renderText({
    input$choice
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there any way to "initialise" the renderUI element without having to load its tabPanel?

Thanks

Comment: Add to server: `outputOptions(output, "choice", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks. This works but only if placed after the assignment of the outputs in the server. I think I prefer this approach because there's less code involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's beacause of lazy loading in shiny.

Have a look at [RStudios article on reactivity](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/understanding-reactivity.html):

> However, you must tell R to run the expresssion for this to happen because R uses a style of execution known as lazy evaluation. In other words, R will not execute an expression until you force it to.

Thus, you have to force `renderUI` to evaluate. That means the only way that your user has a valid input for your `textOutput` is to use `reactive` providing a default value which is updated as soon as `input$choice` is rendered.

**Here** I've added e.g. `reactiveValues` for reactive variable `d` to your code:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("one", textOutput('text')),
    tabPanel("two",
             uiOutput('select'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  c <- reactive({
    list("A", "B", "C")
  })
  d <- reactiveValues(choice = "A")

  output$select <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      inputId = "choice",
      label = "Select input",
      choices = c(),
      selected = 1
    )
  })

  observe({
    req(input$choice)
    d$choice <- input$choice
  })

  output$text <- renderText(
    d$choice
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: While this perfectly works, I would prefer the approach suggested by @ryan-morton because there's less code involved. Thanks for your very fast answer and explanation

Comment: I understand that expression wrapped in reactive({}) will be executed lazily which works like a function, only executes after calling it like f(). But how does renderUI({...}) work? Certainly it does not execute with statement like f(). So, does it execute after user modify something via UI? Then it makes no sense to have any default values.

Comment: `reactive` evaluates eagerly, `renderUI` lazily. Thus, `reactive` serves as default value as long as `renderUI` is not executed. In this particular scenario it makes perfect sense to provide a default with `reactive` while it would not make sense if `rendedUI` is executed directly (e.g.by moving it to TabPanel 1 or by setting the output option `suspendWhenHidden` to `FALSE`)